# Set tabView in the Application

Tags: android

I have Set the tabview in My Application But all tab shows very near to eachother. .  i want to Set the Little Space between then. . .
How it is Possible ?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Shreyash, please stop with the tag spam. Your questions are never related to android-ndk, android-emulator or android-widgets, so *don't use those tags*. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0.5dip"
```

Here, I set    0.5 you can st 1 dp  and you can set a tabdiver.9.png  file.

```
            android:background="#000" />
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="55dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip" android:layout_marginRight="0dip" />
        <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="5dip"
            android:background="#696969" />
        <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1dip" 
            android:background="#000" />
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setIndicator(View)` to build tab from own view, and in your custom view (inflated for example from the XML) set the proper margins / paddings. Refere to my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407300/controlling-tab-colour-state-size-in-a-tabactivity/5670948#5670948) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can add space in the tabview item by giving a margin inside that.
Use the code below.

```
for(int i=0; i < mTabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {  
     View tab = ((ViewGroup) mTabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(i); 
     ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) 
     tab.getLayoutParams(); > p.setMargins(0, 0, 50, 0); > tab.requestLayout();
}
```

---