# Android Tabhost, format text of the tabs

Tags: android, fonts, tabs, size, android-tabhost

I have a tabhost with tabs and the text is set, I just do not like how they are set by default. The text is centered horizontally, but they gravitate to the bottom vertically. I would like to center them completely and resize the text.

I did not see API calls to do this, insight appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answer given by Kocus to my question [Controlling Tab colour-state / size in a TabActivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407300/controlling-tab-colour-state-size-in-a-tabactivity) It covers creating your own custom layouts for the Tabs.

Possibly more than you need as I was looking to do more than just text position and size but it's fairly straight-forward. Also, I haven't found any other way of doing anything with the tabs without using this sort of approach.

Comment: see the accepted answer in the post here, this is what I was going to suggest, you can inflate and set any view you want as the tab indicator.